# Line between two CGPoints in a subview - Cannot determine the frame of nested subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to draw a line between two CGPoints, I'm attaching the picture for reference. [image: View Hierarchy]

I cannot determine the frame of the subview nested in my view hierarchy. I have tried using :-

```
let framev1 = self.view.convertRect(subview.frame, fromView: self.containerView)
```

How can I get exact coordinates of the subview which is deeply nested inside my view hierarchy?

For drawing line between two CGPoint I'm using this function:

```
func drawLineFromPoint(start : CGPoint, toPoint end:CGPoint, ofColor lineColor: UIColor, inView view:UIView) {

    //design the path
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(start)
    path.addLineToPoint(end)

    //design path in layer
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

//How i intent to call the above function to draw a line for me.
Obviously this not working, it draws the line a at (0,0) of the UIViewController.view

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  drawLineFromPoint(CGPointMake(subview1.frame.minX,subview1.frame.midY),  toPoint:CGPointMake(subview2.frame.maxX,subview2.frame.midY ), ofColor: UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(1), inView: self.view)                  
}
```

Comment: Which view is doing the drawing and why aren't you converting the point to that views coordinate system?

Comment: I want to draw a line that goes through middle of the Subview. (Red Circle and lines in the picture)

Comment: @Statik : Can you please share a more explainary piece of code

Comment: This is how I intent to call the function to draw a line.

Comment: So why don't you do the drawing in the view itself or its direct superview?

Answer (score 0):

For your 1st question, try to use this function:

```
func convertRectCorrectly(rect: CGRect, toView view: UIView) -> CGRect {
    if UIScreen.mainScreen().scale == 1 {
        return self.convertRect(rect, toView: view)
    }
    else if self == view {
        return rect
    }
    else {
        var rectInParent = self.convertRect(rect, toView: self.superview)
        rectInParent.origin.x /= UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
        rectInParent.origin.y /= UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
        let superViewRect = self.superview!.convertRectCorrectly(self.superview!.frame, toView: view)
        rectInParent.origin.x += superViewRect.origin.x
        rectInParent.origin.y += superViewRect.origin.y
        return rectInParent
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let framev1 = self.view.convertRectCorrectly(subview.frame, toView: self.containerView)
```

It should return the subview coordinates in parent container view.